# What are domain objects and models in PHP?

Tags: php, oop, object, models

I have been reading about domain objects and domain models - and I kind of understand them, but the more articles I read the more i get confused.

A phrase that keeps popping up is "*Business logic*"! What is meant by this?

Also, what is meant by the word "**domain**"? That confuses me too.

Any advise and examples would be appreciated.

Comment: good question but i think it has been answered before,lets see people response

Comment: Take a look at [this awesome answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5864000/212940) for an explanation of the model layer and [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_model) for an explanation of domain in this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone may be able to give a better whiz-bang computer science answer, but here's the basic meat of it:

Models or domain objects are the "meat" of what makes your application unique. It is that with which your application is concerned. It is the *domain* of your application.

Let's pull that thread a little: every web application has some type of request handling and response mechanism. Every web application (that produces web pages) has some sort of presentation system, even if it's as basic as including a static html page. But not every web application provides a mechanism for retrieving and sending e-mail. Not every web application lets you create and manage events and event calendars.

If your domain is e-mail, then your *domain objects* would be things like `EmailMessage`, `AddressBook`, or `Contact`. Non-domain objects might be something like `FrontController`, or `RouteTable`, or `Dispatcher`. You might make customizations to these items outside of your domain, but they aren't *what your application is about*. Therein lies the difference.

Comment: Thanks for the great reply. This had made things a lot clearer.

Comment: You're welcome. And I'll add that for a more detailed, very useful explanation of the concepts, vascowhite's links are actually quite good.

Comment: I've just looked at vascowhite's links. Very useful too. Thanks guys : )